# PL/SQL XML parsing into relational tables

Tags: oracle, error-handling, plsql, xml-parsing, oracle11g

I am using a PL/SQL procedure for inserting values from XML to relational tables. The XML file resides in an XMLTYPE column. 
Columns of table (OFFLINE_XML) containing XML are

```
ID, XML_FILE, STATUS
```

There are two table in which i want to insert the values i.e. DEPARTMENT and SECTIONS
Structure of DEPARTMENT is as under:-

```
ID, NAME
```

Structure of SECTIONS table is:-

```
ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Now there is a third table (LIST_1) in which i want to insert the values which already exists in both the above mentioned tables.
Structure of LIST_1 is :-

```
ID, DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME,SECTIONS_ID, SECTIONS_NAME
```

XML format is as under:-

```
<ROWSET> 
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP22681352268280797</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
  <SECTIONS_ID>6390135666643567</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection</SECTIONS_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP255555555550797</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT2</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
  <SECTIONS_ID>63901667779243567</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection2</SECTIONS_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
</ROWSET>


DECLARE
  BEGIN
    insert all
        into department (id, name)
           values (unit_id, unit_name)
        into sections (id, name, department _id)
          values ( sect_id, sect_name, department _id)
    select department .id as department _id
          , department.name as department_name
           , sect.id as sect_id
          , sect.name as sect_name
    from OFFLINE_XML
         , xmltable('/ROWSET/DEPARTMENT'
                   passing OFFLINE_XML.xml_file
                   columns
                      "ID"  varchar2(20) path 'UNIT_ID'
                      , "NAME"  varchar2(20) path 'UNIT_NAME'
                  ) department
          , xmltable('/ROWSET/DEPARTMENT'
               passing OFFLINE_XML.xml_file
               columns
                  "ID"  varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_ID'
                  , "NAME"  varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_NAME'
              ) sect
               where status = 3;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate='|| department.id );
    --insert into LIST_1 values(ID,DEPARTMENT_ID, SECTIONS_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME,SECTIONS_NAME);
END;
```

Now the problem is that how can i insert or identify the values on the basis of primary key which already exists in table DEPARTMENT and SECTIONS and thereafter insert the existing values in LIST_1 table.
**------An updated effort --------------**

I came up with another solution but this again is giving me problem. In the under mentioned procedure cursor tends to repeat for every xquery. I don't know how am i going to handle this issue..

```
DECLARE
    department_id varchar2(20);
    department_name varchar2(20);
    sect_id varchar2(20);
    sect_name varchar2(20);
    sections_unit_id varchar2(20);
    var number;
    CURSOR C1 IS
     select
            sect.id as sect_id
          , sect.name as sect_name
          , sect.unit_id  as sections_unit_id
    from OFFLINE_XML
           , xmltable('/ROWSET/DEPARTMENT'
                   passing OFFLINE_XML.xml_file
                   columns
                      "ID"  varchar2(20) path 'UNIT_ID'
                      , "NAME"  varchar2(20) path 'UNIT_NAME'
                  ) DEPARTMENT
          , xmltable('/ROWSET/DEPARTMENT'
               passing OFFLINE_XML.xml_file
               columns
                  "ID"  varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_ID'
                  , "NAME"  varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_NAME'
                  , "DEPARTMENT_ID" varchar2(20) path 'DEPARTMENT_ID'
              ) sect
               where status = 3;

BEGIN
      FOR R_C1 IN C1 LOOP
      BEGIN
      var :=1;
         --insert into sections_temp_1 (id, name)values ( R_C1.sect_id, R_C1.sect_name);
         -- commit;
           dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate='||var);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate='||R_C1.sect_id);
      END;
      var:=var+1;
      END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that first of all you need a little bit more complicated XQuery to extract rows from XMLType field.

There are no need to extract sections and departments separately and after that try to match it back.

Try this variant:

```
select 
  department_id,
  department_name,
  sections_id,
  sections_name
from 
  OFFLINE_XML xml_list,
  xmltable(
    '
      for $dept in $param/ROWSET/DEPARTMENT
        return $dept
    '
    passing xml_list.xml_file as "param"
    columns
      "DEPARTMENT_ID"   varchar2(100) path '//DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID',
      "DEPARTMENT_NAME" varchar2(4000) path '//DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME',
      "SECTIONS_ID"     varchar2(100) path '//DEPARTMENT/SECTIONS_ID',
      "SECTIONS_NAME"   varchar2(4000) path '//DEPARTMENT/SECTIONS_NAME'
  ) section_list
where 
  xml_list.Status = 3
```

[SQL fiddle - 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc8c7/3)

After that you got a dataset which can be outer joined to existing tables on it's primary keys (or something other - depends on required logic) if you want to find if any values already exists:

```
select 
  offline_set.offline_xml_id,
  offline_set.department_id,
  offline_set.department_name,
  offline_set.sections_id,
  offline_set.sections_name,
  nvl2(dept.id,'Y', 'N') is_dept_exists, 
  nvl2(sect.id,'Y', 'N') is_sect_exists 
from 
  (  
    [... skipped text of previous query ...]
  ) offline_set,
  department dept,
  sections   sect
where
  dept.id (+) = offline_set.department_id
  and
  sect.id (+) = offline_set.sections_id
```

[SQL fiddle - 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b3da/1)

Because I actually unaware about logic behind this requirements, I can't suggest any future processing instructions. But it seems that you missed reference to `OFFLINE_XML` table in `LIST_1` which needed to identify source of errors/duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be with Oracle's built in error logging.  Use DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG() to generate a logging table for *each target table* (i.e. SECTION and DEPARTMENT in your case).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_errlog.htm#CEGBBABI).

The syntax for using these tables with INSERT ALL is not intuitive but this is what to do:

```
insert all
    into department (id, name)
       values (unit_id, unit_name)
       log errors into err$_department  ('XML Load failure')
    into sections (id, name, department_id)
      values ( sect_id, sect_name, department_id)
       log errors into err$_section  ('XML Load failure') 
select department.id as department_id
        ....
```

You can put any (short-ish) string into the error log label, but make sure it's something which will help you local the relevant records.  You may wish to set the REJECT LIMIT to some value depending on whether you wish to fail on one (or a couple of) error, or process the whole XML and sort it out afterwards.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BCEGDJDJ).

---

I suggest you use separate logs for each target tables rather one log for both for two reasons:

1. In my expereince solutions which leverage Oracle's built-in feartures tend to scale better and be more robust than hand-rolled code.
2. It's a better fit for what might happen.  You have three circumstances which might cause loading to hurl DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX:

   - Record has duplicate Department ID
   - Record has duplicate Section ID
   - Record has duplicate Department ID *and* duplicate Section ID

Separate tables make it easier to understand what's gone awry.  This is a major boon when loading large amounts of data.

> "i need to inform my user that this much of duplicate entries were
>   found in xml"

You can still do that with two error logs.  Heck, you can even join the error logs into a view called LIST_1 is that is so very important to you.

Comment: i wonder how this is going to help me in inserting already existing values in DEPARTMENT and SECTIONS table to LIST_1 table ?

Comment: I assume you have primary keys defined on those tables: in that case LOG ERROR INTO will handle unique key violations by writing the duplicate records to the log tables.

Comment: That is, use separate logs for each target tables rather one table for both.

Comment: actually my requirement is that i need to have all duplicate entries in one table. This for future reference, i need to inform my user that this much of duplicate entries were found in xml.

Comment: please consider my updated effort also. This may assist you in understanding my requirement.